# Avoid dead-end when flagging for migration and site isn't listed

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

This is the last step a person might take before hitting a dead-end:

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

I recently wanted to flag a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768011/coding-style-of-this-simple-function) on SO as belonging on Code Review, and couldn't because it isn't in the list of other sites in the flagging popup, right after clicking the above option.

I opened a [Meta SO discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341964/flag-for-migration-to-code-review-no-joy) requesting that Code Review be added to the list, and it was quickly marked a duplicate of [Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review). That's correct, but I wasted my time and that of others because the latter is 13th in the search results when searching SO Meta for "flag migration to code review".

This is a request that **a "Belongs on other" option is added** to the "Flagging -> Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration" page of the flagging popup. This could be an alias of "Other (needs moderator attention)" as suggested on the [highly-voted Meta SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review).

At the very least, add a message explaining why not every site is listed, along with a link to more information.

This is done in the spirit of avoiding dead-ends in the flagging popup. At every point, the user chooses the most precise option for flagging, but ends up at a point where there is no option but to go back up and find something more general.

[image: migration page of flagging popup]

Comment: It can't be *other (needs moderator attention)* because that assumes a moderator knows which site the question is on-topic, and they honestly don't and shouldn't. So that leaves your *add a message explaining why not every site is listed,* the option with the least impact, assuming we have a link where we can users redirect to.